# How to generate a MySQL IS NOT NULL condition in CakePHP?

Tags: mysql, arrays, cakephp, find, field

I'm trying to get a subset of results as a virtualField for use in my view. I may even be way off on how I'm approaching this, but here's what I've done so far:

I started with this question here: [CakePHP virtualField find all not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458331/cakephp-virtualfield-find-all-not-null/20458367?noredirect=1#comment30568626_20458367) which lead to  [this little beauty](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#virtual-fields-and-model-aliases).

Now I have an issue where the find statement passing (Array) into the MySQL.

My code looks like:

```
class Transaction extends AppModel {
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
    $this->virtualFields['Accounts'] = $this->find("all", array("conditions" => array("account !=" => null)));
}
```

And I'm seeing:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

SQL Query: SELECT `Transaction`.`id`, `Transaction`.`name`, 
`Transaction`.`person_id`, `Transaction`.`account`, (Array) 
AS `Transaction__Accounts` FROM `my_database`.`transactions` 
AS `Transaction` WHERE `Transaction`.`person_id` = (2)
```

I've also tried `$this->Transaction->find` and `"Transaction.account !="`, to no avail. I've found some other issues with the (Array) but none that help my situation. Any pointers in the right direction would be great.

Comment: I think I'm just going to grab this in the controller for now... but I'm going to leave the question up as it seems valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:** your query results are an array, and you're telling SQL to assign a field name to each query result containing that array - virtual fields are only made to contain single level variables like strings.

**Solution:** use a `join` structure onto itself with those conditions which will return a nested result set along with each of your results. Use [CakePHP's model relationships](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) to do this:

```
<?php    
class Transaction extends AppModel {
    var $hasMany = array(
        'Accounts' => array(
            'className' => 'Transaction',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array('Accounts.account IS NOT NULL')
        )
    );
}    
?>
```

**Example output:**

```
Array(
    'Transaction' => array( // transaction data),
    'Accounts' => array( // associated transaction data with account set to null
)
```

Now, as you can probably gather from that result, if you return 1000 rows from `Transaction`, you'll get **all** results from `Accounts` nested into **each Transaction result**. This is far from ideal. From here, you can either make the join conditions more specific to target relevant `Accounts` records, or this is not the right approach for you.

Other approaches could be:

- Accounts model, uses `Transaction` database table, implicit find conditions are that `account is null`
- Manual query to retrieve these results in the [afterFind() method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#afterfind) of your `Transaction` model, which will retrieve these results **once**, and you'll then `return array_merge($accounts, $transactions)`

Comment: I will try these (that last one in particular) and let you know what happens. Great explanation at the very least!

Comment: @RandyHall if it were me, I'd go the afterFind way

Comment: I'm trying it now. Without writing the whole thing out, will `$this->find("all", array("conditions" => array("not" => array("account" => null))));` give me ALL records where account != null, or only a subset of the original $results?

Comment: It's a seperate query, so it won't be affected by your original query conditions. If you have trouble with it, go deeper and just use `$this->query("SQL HERE")` - but you shouldn't have trouble.

Comment: I put 

        `$accounts = $this->find("all", array("conditions" => array("Transaction.account !=" => null)));` in my model's afterFind, and my server just returns 500 with generic server error page.

Comment: Perhaps I should just write out a conditional in my view to only output what I want, rather than trying to separate it here. Maybe I'm making this harder than it needs to be.

Comment: My guess would be to do a manual query using `$this->query('SQL here')` - because `$this->find()` in a find callback is probably triggering another `afterFind` and creating an endless loop. `$this->query()` is manual, but might not have the same effect.